# (Cucumber) Multiple tags are not working properly

Tags: cucumber

```
Feature: Test

    Background: 
        Given step1

    #--------------------------------------- Case:1 ---------------------------------------
    @tag2 @tag3
    Scenario: Test1
        When step2
        Then step3
    
    #--------------------------------------- Case:2 ---------------------------------------
    @tag2 @tag1
    Scenario: Test2
        When step2
        Then step3

    #--------------------------------------- Case:3 ---------------------------------------
    @tag1 @tag3
    Scenario: Test3
        When step2
        Then step3
```

On running this feature with these "@tag1 or @tag2 and not @tag3" tags, Case:2 and Case:3 are get executed.

It should not execute cases having @tag3 but it is executing Case:3. How this possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You really need to add additional supporting information to your question in order to receive a useful answer.  It is useful for others and will help avoid your question being downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

To get the proper result, have to run the feature file using the following tag expression:
"(@tag1 or @tag2) and (not @tag3)"